# CSS in shadow DOM with Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Is there any possibility with webpack 5 to correctly generate a bundle with CSS injectable in a shadow DOM?
If I try to load some CSS with the new assets, url are not transformed, but I need them to be adapted to integrate with the generated bundle.
For example I have a CSS file like the following:

```
/* src/components/header.css */
#logo {
  background-image: url('./images/logo.png');
}
```

It would be nice if webpack can url encode or replace the url to be embedded in a shadow dom.
If I configure webpack as follows:

```
...
module.rules: [{
  test: /\.css$/,
  oneOf: [
    {
      resourceQuery: /raw/,  // import css from 'path/to/file.css?raw'
      type: 'asset/source',
      use: [
        {loader: 'css-loader'}
      ]
    },{
      ...
    }
  ]
}]
...
```

The loaded string isn't CSS anymore, but is some Webpack script. If I remove the `use` part in the rule the CSS is loaded without changes.
There is any plugin that can make the CSS inlining and load it as string?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use Webpack "style-loader" plugin with insert parameter.

```
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
            options: {
              injectType: "lazyStyleTag",
              insert: function insertIntoTarget(element, options) {
                var parent = options.target || document.head;
                parent.appendChild(element);
              },
            },
          },
```

Refer to [this](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#custom-elements-shadow-dom) for more details.